# Rail 3.2 saves id as null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

can`t understand why

```
Product.new(params[:product])
```

in my controller with parametr :id save id as null?
 I have form with 2 parameters. :id and :des
when i use console

```
r = Product.new r.id = ... r.des= ... r.save
```

All OK
But if i use params 
 :des saved in base and :id saved is null. 
Add some code
 this is controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @pr = Product.find(:all)
end
def new
    @pr = Product.new()
end
def create
    @pr = Product.new(params[:product])
    if @pr.save
        flash[:notice] = "All OK"
        redirect_to products_path
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Errors"
        redirect_to products_path
    end

end end
```

and this is form

```
<%= form_for @pr do |f| %>
<%= f.label :id %> <br>
<%= f.number_field :id %><br>
<%= f.label :des%> <br>
<%= f.text_area :des%> <br>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

id`s I need fill manualy
---------------- MY OWN ANSWER ------
in controller I add this string \

```
@pr.id = params[:product][:id]
```

but why not work

```
@pr = Product.new(params[:product])
```

I don`t understand.

Comment: Rails handles setting the id for you in a typical database. Do you have a special usecase that requires it to be set manually?

Comment: are your params in a hash called product? how are you posting the form?

Comment: Do you call save somewhere in the action? Calling `Product.new` doesn't save anything to DB, you have to call save on the object after. Or call `Product.create` directly if you prefer to create the object AND save it to the DB at the same time.